# BeautifulSoup hangs when using find

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a problem with the `bs4` package.

I have a `html` document, like this one:

```
data = """<html><head></head><body>
<p> this is tab </p>
<img src="image.jpg">
</body></html>
"""
```

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
soup.find_all("a")
```

When I run it, `bs4` is still in a loop and doesn't return anything, maybe because in some `HTML` data the tag `a` doesn't exist.

Many thanks.
1. Yes, above example working correctly.
2. But, in my case. data is a variable with multi lines html string

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = open("file.htm").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
soup.find_all("a")
```

3. Please test with my file: [file.htm](https://mega.nz/#!GBRgjKBJ!OJxzCOlg65Uj8fSGkP2UEdHkPoKlHCN2O_nveZZivag) 
4. I'm using beautifulsoup4==4.4.1. Python 3.5.1 
5. Thanks again.

Comment: it works for me by returning empty list.

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup are you using?  You can display this using `import bs4; print bs4.__version__`

Answer (score 4):

Try using the builtin `html.parser`, it works even with invalid HTML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<html><head></head><body>
<p> this is tab </p>
<img src="image.jpg">
</body></html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("a")
```

Comment: yes!, i've try all parser, only html5lib work correctly. other parser some time make wrong html output.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why would your program hangs when using `find_all`, it might take a while if the html page is large but it shouldn't hang.

Here are a few things you can try:

- If you are downloading the web page prior to parsing it, that might cause the hanging. Use [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to detect where exactly the program hangs, add this line to the start of your code `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and track it from there
- Make sure you installed `Html5Lib` by running `pip freeze | grep html5lib`, if it doesn't exist install it with `pip install html5lib`
- In a similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536072/detecting-beautifulsoup-freeze), someone mentioned they got it fixed by upgrading `BeautifulSoup`, try that with: `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`

In the [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) doc, they recommend using specific parsers with certain Python versions:

> If you can, I recommend you install and use lxml for speed.
>   If you’re using a version of Python 2 earlier than 2.7.3, or a version of Python 3 earlier than 3.2.2, it’s essential that you install `lxml` or `html5lib` – Python’s built-in HTML parser is just not very good in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while working on an already decoded element of a page, and I could resolve by forcing a fresh decode of the same subtree.

This was running indefinitely and systematically on my snippet:

```
spans = subtree.find_all ("span")
```

This instead worked as expected:

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(subtree), "html.parser")
spans = soup2.find_all ("span")
```